# Simplest way to connect Mist to a node

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

What do you guys think the simplest way to connect Mist to geth running on another machine?

I'm running geth 1.8.23 on another machine using `./geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal"` and it has completed a full sync.

I'm currently using an ssh tunnel to connect to that node and running mist with `--rpc http://127.0.0.1:8545`. The tunnel appears to be working and it looks like mist is connecting to it, but it's always reporting my local node state as "sync starting" and mist never switches over to it from the remote node. There's nothing jumping out at me here as to what or if there's a problem.

[image: node status]

I do get some messages in the shell when I launch mist:
`[2019-03-10T13:04:58.359] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - Sanity check failed for Geth Error: Unable to find "1.8.21" in Geth output
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (C:\CCW\Mist-win64-0-11-1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\ethereum-client-binaries\src\index.js:632:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)`

and: 
`[2019-03-10T13:05:14.218] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32000, message: 'notifications not supported' }`